# using socket io how to share a message to all users of Room except sender

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am using socket io and express. i want to broadcast my message to all users of room but insted of users of that room all users who are connected recive message. Room id is room id

```
const app = require('express')();
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const path = require('path');
app.use(cors({origin: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
io.on('connection', async (socket) => {
console.log('user connected');
}
```

Now This is message block

````
 socket.on('message' , async (data)=>{
//want to broadcast message to all users except sender 
//Room is Group1Room and room id is RoomId
io.emit('message', {message:"hello" , socketId:socket.id})
//recive message 
io.on('message' , (data)=>{
console.log('data is ' data);
})
}

```ata,{ where: { id } });
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

socket.emit is used to emit an event globally.All user connected to socket will will listen and get data. for sharing a message in room use

```
socket.broadcast.to(roomid).emit()
```

your code will be like that

```
socket.broadcast.to(event).emit( 'message' , {message:message,
socketId:socket.id
    });
```